# $.getScript rangeerror?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stylus, getscript

I'm using [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) to render some code into CSS on the clientside.

If I include the `stylus.min.js` file in my initial load everything works fine.

However because stylus is quite large I would like to delay loading that file until it's needed and grab it with jquery's 1.8.2 `$.getScript()`.

Doing so gives me this error:

```
RangeError: stylus:947:26
   943|       &[data-aaa="1"]
   944|           margin-top 2em
   945|       &[data-bbb="1"]
   946|           transition 1s
   947|           margin-top -2em
---------------------------------^

Maximum call stack size exceeded


    at f.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:26233)
    at i.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:17594)
    at f.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:26106)
    at i.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:17594)
    at f.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:26106)
    at i.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:17594)
    at f.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:26106)
    at i.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:17594)
    at f.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:26106)
    at i.visit (http://f264bc8tf77nkh.cloudfront.net/static/1akh96ita/ace/stylus-min.js?_=1465163994282:4:17594)
```

Is it that there is some limitation on scripts that are loaded via getScript that I can turn off?

Thanks.

Loading code:

```
load = function(templateName, callback) {
  if (_.str.endsWith(templateName, '.js')) {
    var url = '//' + settings.cdn + '/static/' + settings.assetsTime +'/' + templateName

    $.getScript(url, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      if (callback) callback()
    });
    return
  }
}
```

I load many other files with this same code and it works fine.

Comment: Please show us the exact code you are using to load the file.

Comment: @jfriend00 loading code added. Also jquery is v 1.8.2 maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Before calling getScript, I would check if it was already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM the problem was in minification.